# String filter not working in API platform

Tags: php, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am using API platform v1.2.0 on Symfony 4.2.11 and I am trying to make plain simple filter for filtering users in mine app by using annotations like suggested on API platform documentation page. But they do not filter data, I still receive all items in response.

Besides annotation I have tried to add filter as a service as sugested on API platform website. But in that case, I get an error:

`Attribute "bind" on service "app.string_filter" cannot be inherited from "_defaults" when a "parent" is set. Move your child definitions to a separate file`

**To avoid any confusion I have tried both ways independently.**

- Annotations do not work, endpoint simply works as without them.
- When I declare service it fails as in upper error message.

This is code of mine entity with annotations:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Security\User\JWTUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_user")
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"username": "partial"})
 */
class User implements JWTUserInterface
{

...
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you !

Comment: Using the annotation method, can you show us your request to fetch the filtered data?